# WARNING: JSF1069: Disabling the JSF 2.0 Facelets ViewHandler as an older FaceletViewHandler

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee

I created a Java EE web application with Spring, Hibernate and JSF 2 but when I run the application the JSF component (PrimeFaces) does not appear and I got this warning:

> WARNING: JSF1069: Disabling the JSF 2.0 Facelets ViewHandler as an
>   older FaceletViewHandler, com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler, has
>   been explicitly configured. If this is not desired behavior, remove
>   the older FaceletViewHandler and library from your application.

But I already inserted the JSF lib.

Comment: I strongly suggest you tell your application server to be less French somehow.

Comment: I'm guessing you're explicitly trying to configure Facelets for JSF. If I recall correctly, Facelets is built in to JSF 2.0, so you don't need to use the old library anymore. Just remove any Facelets configuration you have in your application, it *should* be the new default.

Comment: thanks for help but when i removed facelet lib and configuration from faces config the worning is disappear but jsf conponant still does not appear

Comment: For this check out the URL pattern of your faces servlet in web.xml.

Comment: @user2338085 That's probably a different problem then.

Comment: @skuntsel : i puted    "<servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF 2.0, you won't need to add the Facelets library. You will have something like this in your faces-config.xml:

```
<application>  
  <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>  
</application>
```

Remove this and remove the facelets dependency from your project.

Comment: the probleme now is that the prime faces componant does not work

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Do they render correctly? Do you get JavaScript errors? With JSF 2.0 you definitely shouldn't need to add the Facelets view handler.

Comment: thank u , i mean that  when i run application my home page is empty,i think that i have a problem with jsf2 because when i put my url pattern *.jas the home page is empty but when i put *.xhtml it work but a lot of exeption are generated